# Getting streaming audio to play with MediaPlayer class on Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hello I am currently new to android development I been working on the examples in the Dev Guide in the android website. I want to get a stream from a server I have to play in the emulator when I insert the url it doesn't seam to want to play. My question is there a way to get the emulator to play audio or is it all enabled also does `MediaPlayer` require a special kind of format like mp3 or ogg ? 
This is the code i am running on my 'onCreate()' method.

```
MediaPlayer mp - new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(MY_URL_);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Hope you guys can help my out.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, it works on my device and it doesn't work on emulator. So I guess you need device to hear the sound.

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to set a flag "-useaudio" in the command build scripts, but now it seems the emulator won't play sound, or at least mine won't.